# How to write output in terminal that contains specific text in line

Tags: python, linux, terminal, scrapy

I tried to use 'scrapy' to crawled web URL but I can not use '>' to write into file directly.

I also tried on 'script' command to capture text on terminal screen, it worked but it wrote everything that use a huge storage in the few time. I plan to run over night and I afraid my storage be come full.

for example text from terminal;

```
2020-11-05 17:22:10 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'seek.bloggang.com': <GET http://seek.bloggang.com>
2020-11-05 17:22:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://pantip.com/topic/39275448> (referer: https://pantip.com/tag/Marriage_Visa)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/noah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/noah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
```

I want only line that contains URL (in  tag) like

```
2020-11-05 17:22:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://pantip.com/topic/39275448> (referer: https://pantip.com/tag/Marriage_Visa)
```

Do you have any idea for this case?

Best regards.

PS. I attached code to you too.

```
import scrapy

class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"
    allowed_domains = ['pantip.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pantip.com']

    def __init__(self):
        self.links=[]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.links.append(response.url)
        for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
```

Comment: How is this related to bash? Looks to me like a Python problem, but you did not tag is as _python_.